# Spring: not-null property references a null or transient value when using @RepositoryRestController

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-rest

I am facing a strange issue. In my spring app, I have a controller which saves a record in the db.

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping(WiseUrls.PEOPLE_URL)
public class PeopleController {

   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
         .getLogger(PeopleController.class.getName());

   @Autowired
   PeopleService peopleService;

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity<PeopleResponse> create(
         @RequestBody PeopleRequest annotationRequest) {

      PeopleResponse resp = new PeopleResponse();

      resp.setAnnotation(peopleService.create(annotationRequest.getAnnotation()));

      return new ResponseEntity<PeopleResponse>(resp, HttpStatus.OK);
   }

}
```

The People class looks like

```
@Entity
public class People extends User  {

  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2385409579929134474L;   

  @JsonProperty
  @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @NotNull
  PeopleJob peopleJob;

  @JsonProperty
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  PeopleAddress peopleAddress;

  public PeopleJob getPeopleJob() {
     return peopleJob;
  }

  public void setPeopleJob(PeopleJob peopleJob) {
     this.peopleJob = peopleJob;
  }

  public PeopleAddress getPeopleAddress() {
     return PeopleAddress;
  }

  public void setPeopleAddress(PeopleAddress peopleAddress) {
     this.peopleAddress = peopleAddress;
  }
}
```

And this is the service

```
@Service
public class PeopleService {

   @Autowired
   PeopleRepository repository;

   public People create(
         People peopleAPI) {

      People dao = repository.save(peopleAPI);
      return dao;
   }
}
```

If I use `@RestController` annotation in the controller class the object is saved fine. But if I use `@RepositoryRestController` which I need to use, I get this error

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : my.app.DB.models.People.job
   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:623) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:258) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:303) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:778) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:751) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.4.Final.jar:5.1.4.Final]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:508) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   at my.app.Service.services.PeopleService.create(PeopleService.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
   at my.app.Service.controllers.PeopleController.create(PeopleController.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:244) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at my.app.Service.filters.OptionsRequestFilter.doFilter(OptionsRequestFilter.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks !!

Comment: validation fails on hibernate level when you do repository.save(). check in debug mode , when it become null. think in null in controller 
 -  annotationRequest.getAnnotation(). check it for RestController andRepositoryRestController  cases

Comment: @sbjavateam You are right. Deserialization gives null values in case of RepositoryRestController :/ but not in RestController. Not sure why?

Comment: in case RepositoryRestController  , all fields  for annotationRequest are null or only peopleAPI field ?  also do you use spring boot ?

Comment: in debug mode you can check what type of  ObjectMapper used by spring rest data and spring rest contoller. dependence on your configuration they might be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from spring data rest : [Adding custom (de)serializers to Jackson’s ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.custom-jackson-deserialization)

> Sometimes the behavior of the Spring Data REST’s ObjectMapper, which
>   has been specially configured to use intelligent serializers that can
>   turn domain objects into links and back again, may not handle your
>   domain model correctly. There are so many ways one can structure your
>   data that you may find your own domain model isn’t being translated to
>   JSON correctly. It’s also sometimes not practical in these cases to
>   try and support a complex domain model in a generic way. Sometimes,
>   depending on the complexity, it’s not even possible to offer a generic
>   solution.

If for rest controller object comes with correct fields  , check in debug what heppens during object mapping process.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. My jackson configuration was such that the camel case would be converted to snake case in the json. But with RepositoryRestController this wasn't happening. When I added the snake case names to JsonProperty it worked. Cheers !!